# C# Regex extract multiple lines between markers

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract the Cross Street values which exist after the `Cross Streets~` line until the next line which includes a tilde character somewhere-- in this case it's a Phone number in another case it may just be a tilde on a line by itself or some other field.  It has all been pulled into a string which includes `\r\n` characters. A subset of the string is shown below.

```
\r\nVenue:~SOLDOTNA\r\nCross Streets~\r\nDEAD END / STERLING HWY\r\n S KOBUK ST\r\nPhone:~(999) 999-9999\r\nQuadrant:~ES 1\r\n
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015.  From the following example, I would ultimately like to obtain a string containing `"DEAD END / STERLING HWY, S KOBUK ST"`

```
Venue:~SOLDOTNA
Cross Streets~
DEAD END / STERLING HWY
 S KOBUK ST
Phone:~(999) 999-9999
```

I have spent hours trying multiple SO suggestions to no avail.  I have most recently tried the following:

```
Regex.Matches(data, "Cross Streets~\r\n(.+?)\r\n.+?~", RegexOptions.Singleline)[0].Groups
{System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection}
    Count: 2
    IsReadOnly: true
    IsSynchronized: false
    SyncRoot: {Cross Streets~
DEAD END / STERLING HWY
 S KOBUK ST
Phone:~}
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
```

Thinking that `Groups[1]` would contain the information I'm looking for, but it only includes the first line.

```
Regex.Matches(data, "Cross Streets~\r\n(.+?)\r\n.+?~", RegexOptions.Singleline)[0].Groups[1]
{DEAD END / STERLING HWY}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Index: 149
    Length: 23
    Name: "1"
    Success: true
    Value: "DEAD END / STERLING HWY"
```

Though not the same environment as mine, here's a regex link as requested via the SO wiki regex article... (it doesn't match at all, though in my C# Immediate Window, I am getting matches as shown above, just not exactly what I want.)

https://regex101.com/r/HpHSra/3

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex to do that. You can use String.Split method and search for your required result.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string x = @"Venue:~SOLDOTNA
Cross Streets~
DEAD END / STERLING HWY
 S KOBUK ST
Phone:~(999) 999-9999";


        string[] allResults =   x.Split( new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToArray();
        foreach(string y in allResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y + " = " +y.Length);
        }


        Console.WriteLine();


        if(allResults.Contains("Cross Streets~") && allResults.Length >  Array.IndexOf(allResults,"Cross Streets~")+1 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Expeced Result : " +  allResults[ Array.IndexOf(allResults,"Cross Streets~")+1 ]);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is fiddler : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zvBhMF